# Android studio tools layout

Tags: android, android-studio

i want my logcat to be attached to the DDMS but now is showing like this
[image]

Why this is happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag your logcat window beside the ADB Logs tab, and let it snap into the window.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Try to drag to Devices tab I think It's automatically should add into it.